# .NET 7: a connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-7.0

After I migrated my project to `.NET 7` I had to add the `TrustServerCertificate=true;` setting  in the connection string otherwise the following error is thrown: `SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process`.

In .NET 5 or 6 this is not necessary. Can anyone tell me why it is necessary to add this setting in the connection string?

**LOCAL CONNECTION STRING:**

```
Server=localhost;Database=Xpz;Integrated Security=SSPI;TrustServerCertificate=true;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because of a breaking change in the SQL Server driver, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#encrypt-true

Answer (score 15):

Write the connection string in **appsettings.json** file:
add "TrustServerCertificate=True"

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=SERVER_NAME;Database=DB_NAME;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;",
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with the .net 7.0 that just came out. TrustServerCertificate=True attribute is required for me

Answer (score 0):

Add **Encrypt=False;** to the connection string

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).